# Can't type with my keyboard jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a problem with my localhost Jupyter notebooks , since a few day , I can't typing in any cell on new notebook or existing notebook , sometimes it's work and after execute one cell , the same problem reborn
I already tried to restart kernel and shutdown, but it's doesn't work
If someone can't help me , i will be grateful to him